# I lost my 12 or 24 words to my bitcoin wallet. I just have my password

Tags: private-key, mnemonic-seed, seed

I lost my 12 or 24 words to my bitcoin wallet. I just have my password. How can I get them back? Is there a software or a website where I can enter my password and get my asset back?

Comment: Do you still have access to the original wallet via the password?

Comment: Related: [I have lost my wallet, what can I do?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/103688/13866)

Answer (score 2):

Sadly if you lost your seed phrase (12 or 24 words) you won't be able to regenerate your private key and get your funds control back. Best advice, look harder where you wrote it or stored it.

PS. Never write your seed phrase in any online place or take any picture, just piece of paper very well stored.