# I lost my wallet, can someone just help me with my investigation?

Tags: wallet-recovery

Im from Argentina, living in Spain, so im sorry for me english.
I will try to explain:
Back in 2013, i had a butterfly equipment...i bought one to resell in Argentina, and i did mining like few months, and i remember using a "pool" to do that.
I sold machine, forgot totally about btc, i even change my laptop many times....

2021: Im desperated for this covid problem, im inmigrant in foreign country and is really hard. So i tried to remember things...to search in my email...in my google activity...etc...etc
I found out the pool, was Bitminter, i realized was like not working, but i wrote to support and they answered to me right away, cause my hotmail adress was no longer valid !!
So they kindly attached my google account, and i logged in!
I saw just cents of btc....and i realize i had the option "pay out auto", and i can see the transactions made to my "wallet"....but i HAVE NO IDEA WHAT WALLET I USE....even what pc i was using .... i change pc all time... is so frustrating.

[image]

some kind soul with any idea? thanks a lot !!!

Comment: There is still about 1/6 of a bitcoin sitting in that address: https://blockstream.info/address/1KVCgW4yojgoP2j4RCADHNCKkND2VqteXA. Unfortunately, there is no way to find out what wallet you were using from the address. You can find a few pointers here: [I have lost my wallet, what can I do?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/103688/5406).  If it was a wallet on your laptop, it's probably lost. Maybe you used blockchain.info or a similar wallet? Then it might also be tied to your old email address, though.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I have lost my wallet, what can I do?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/103688/i-have-lost-my-wallet-what-can-i-do)

Comment: yes...i saw that post, i also thought could be blockchain, so i tried to log in, they said "email is not supported", but they give chance to put email to recover, and it seems my email (always the same since then) isnt attached.... but i do remember the wallet needed registration, but maybe my memory fails.... thanks a lot

Comment: If you're using your real name as your screen name, you should probably change it, especially since if you ever recover the bitcoin in the future, people will know you have it which can make you the target of malicious actors.

Answer (score 1):

too many clues means no clue at all. there isn't no clue. you already said u changed laptop manytimes . just forget about. you can't dnothing without the backup.

but if you using some online wallet to receive that btc. you can search your email to see if there are record fromexchange or online wallets. this is the only chance. good luck.