# Recovery after losing wallet.dat and formatting hard disk

Tags: recover-private-key, lost-wallet

I have received the bitcoin way back in 2013 in Bitcoin Core. At that time I don't know about the importance of wallet.dat - I have formatted my hard disk and install Bitcoin Core again in 2017 but there it didn't show my Bitcoin in my balance. I have my Bitcoin Key.

I meant "Bitcoin Key" is my Public Key on which I got my bitcoin. Is there any other way to get my Bitcoin back if I didn't get my original wallet.dat of Bitcoin Core?

How can I get my bitcoin back?
How can I get to know my Private Key?

Comment: Related: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/103688/5406

Answer (score 4):

Your money is lost without at least one of

- a backup of important data from the hard disk before it was formatted
- a backup of the `wallet.dat` file
- a note of the private key

There is no way to recover the private key from other information. If there was, Bitcoin would be completely unsafe and unusable.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I get to know my Private Key?

That's what your `wallet.dat` contained. You cannot get that back if you've lost your `wallet.dat`. Otherwise, Bitcoin would be worth $0 as anyone could just "make up" private keys with any amount of Bitcoin.

Since the `wallet.dat` was long deleted, re-installing Bitcoin Core is insufficient—there is nothing left for Bitcoin Core to guess your old key.

Comment: I meant "Bitcoin Key" is my Public Key on which I got my bitcoin.

Is there any other way to get my Bitcoin back if I didn't get my original wallet.dat of Bitcoin Core?

Comment: If you lost your wallet.dat, have no backups or dumps of it, I'm afraid there is no way to recover your coins.

Comment: Oh..okay.Thansk for your comment.

Comment: Hi Coiner, I edited your answer to remove rude phrasing. We expect users on this site to respectfully communicate with each other.

Answer (score 0):

there is still a minor hope for you this is the [software](https://www.ccleaner.com/recuva) which recover the data even from the formatted hard drive if you successfully recovered your wallet.dat file then replace the file with your new wallet.dat of bitcoin core which has Zero balance.