# I lost my phone where I stored my 12 word recovery phrase. How can I get back my bitcoins?

Tags: wallet-recovery

I lost my phone where I stored my 12 word recovery phrase. How can I get back my bitcoins? I still know my password and email but i dont have access to my email again after i lost my phone.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I have lost my wallet, what can I do?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/103688/i-have-lost-my-wallet-what-can-i-do)

Answer (score 2):

Sorry no way.

Never digitise your Seed Recovery information, except to a hardware wallet or other dedicated airgapped device. Certainly never on anything capable of connecting to the internet.

Etched onto steel plates, stored in multiple secure locations far from home, secure passphrase separately from 24-word mnemonic

Answer (score 1):

It's gone. Next time have physical backup on carved steel or something. And multiple backups at different locations too.

Answer (score 1):

The question is: how many of those words do you remember well? How many are in the “may be” range? How many have gone for ever? Write those information down as soon as possible and may be that a proper private service can help you, but it will cost you very much, so much that if you have few BTC coins to recover you will never able to justify.