# 2011 bitcoin HUNT

Tags: wallet-recovery

I am here for some help. I bought bitcoin in 2011 and I unfortunately can't remember for the life of me which wallet I kept it in. I am hoping maybe someone can give me a little guidance. If I had bitcoin core wallet back then how would I access it today? In 2011 was there a seed phrase? Would it have been saved straight to my PC? Any direction will be greatly appreciated and of course anyone that provides me with any useful info that leads me to getting my wallet back a reward will be in store.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I have lost my wallet, what can I do?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/103688/i-have-lost-my-wallet-what-can-i-do)

Comment: in 2011 you probably had a wallet.dat file, containing each randomly generated address, no seed phrase

Answer (score 0):

Try blockchain.com

They used to be blockchain.info

You can go to login and check if you have any wallet ID associated with your mail.

You can also check if you got any mail from wallet@blockchain.info way back

Good luck