# How do I see if I've invested in bitcoin

Tags: investing

I can't remember if I ever invested in bitcoin how can I check can someone please help

Comment: Related: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/103688/i-have-lost-my-wallet-what-can-i-do

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I have lost my wallet, what can I do?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/103688/i-have-lost-my-wallet-what-can-i-do)

Answer (score 2):

Typically you would know because you would have the keys to the wallet in your possession. It's also possible you invested on an exchange and in that case you wouldn't have the keys, and you would need to check with the exchange. Perhaps a simple search in your email for "bitcoin" or "crypto" will reveal if you have any accounts that you could look into further.