# What wallet or service could this “address” be for?

Tags: blockchain.info, wallet-recovery

Located an old crypto address on my old laptop prior to recycling - I have no idea what exchange if any - I have a number of passwords that may be associated with it, but have no idea where to start - any suggestions?  The address / account looks like this (made a few edits).  8fe2e2e3-7f26-46ab-b181-e6831 eee36c8

Answer (score 1):

> 8fe2e2e3-7f26-46ab-b181-e6831 eee36c8

The only Hexadecimal numbers with hyphens that I recall seeing are the so-called Wallet-IDs provided by custodial services to account  holders.

An example would be
[Simplecoin](https://client.simplecoin.eu/en/post/wallet-id-and-adress) but I'm sure there are many more. I recall [blockchain.com](https://www.blockchain.com/learning-portal/wallet-faq) have used Wallet-IDs with a similar form.

I can't think of any real† wallets that use Wallet-IDs of that form.

---

See also

- [I have lost my wallet, what can I do?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/103688/13866)

---

† self custodial, not requiring you to trust any 3rd party service.

Comment: Thanks Yes is was a blockchain.com account - - - password worked and my treasure hunt ended with a zero balance in the account. I was hoping to share fee with someone who helped me figure this out but the dream is over!  thanks for the time and response - much appreciated. RP