# I have a privat key and my wallet adress but dont know where I made my wallet

Tags: private-key, money-transfer

How can I transfer the money to for example binance.
I have the private key and my wallet address but dont remember where I made the wallet (on which site).

Comment: Did you search in your email inbox which was the exchange?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I have lost my wallet, what can I do?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/103688/i-have-lost-my-wallet-what-can-i-do)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to know in which site you originally created your wallet, all you need to do is import your private keys to some wallet software you trust like, for example, Electrum wallet for BTC, Metamask/Trust wallet for ERC-20 token (i.e. WBTC). And then just transfer your funds from that.