# I bought Bitcoin from a Bitcoin ATM at a gas station years ago and I lost the receipt

Tags: lost-bitcoins, bitcoin-atm

I bought Bitcoin from a Bitcoin ATM at a gas store when Bitcoin first came out years ago and I lost the paper receipt they gave me but I have a picture of the paper receipt and it has a code at the bottom. Can I still get access too the Bitcoin and if so how and where do I enter this code on this receipt?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I have lost my wallet, what can I do?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/103688/i-have-lost-my-wallet-what-can-i-do)