# Lost Bitcoin from 2011 or 2012

Tags: blockchain.info, unconfirmed-transactions, wallet-recovery, bitcoin-core-accounts

So I wanted to look at some pornography on the internet in either 2011 or 2012 I purchased $50 worth of Bitcoin proceeded to purchase the 29.99 internet porn but there was like $18 left over and I was very naive at the time about Bitcoin and tried and tried to get that back into my bank account not knowing that you have to sell it back so I just chalked it up as $18 gone well I was informed that Bitcoin is almost $50,000 per coin now and I know at the time they were less than a dollar a coin so I've got 18 to 20 Bitcoin out there somewhere how do I go about finding it? I remember the bank account it came from I remember using PayPal to do the transaction what do I need to do and how do I do it?

Comment: Does [I have lost my wallet, what can I do?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/103688/5406) answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

Did you just sent the $50 bitcoin into the wallet the site provided to you ? Or you had it purchased into your personal wallet before you transferred to the wallet or scan page the pornography site gave you ..

If you did sent it directly to the pornography site my friend the rest of it is gone into the site
And you you did sent it to your personal wallet before you sent the $29.99 to the site look your wallet up it’s in there