# can you find bitcoins on an old pc that you have not used in years

Tags: lost-bitcoins

My Dad has an old Windows pc on which he should have like 200 bitcoins from when bitcoin was new somewhere on it and i am trying to help him to find them but we dont know where to look and my dad can't remember where they are is there a way to find them using a usb or anything

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I have lost my wallet, what can I do?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/103688/i-have-lost-my-wallet-what-can-i-do)