# lost bitcoin card purchased from a drug store many years ago

Tags: lost-bitcoins

We know the CVS location and can probably find the year and month. Without locating the physical card, is there any other way to recover the value? I know that LibertyX does transactions now, but do not know whether they were involved many years ago. thx